# Setting a text as default table cell text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set "Cell [" + x + ", " + y + "]" as default cell text if nothing is filled in the Sample Cell Data text box. And if a value is enetered into the Sample Data Cell textbox, the only the value will be shown onto each individual cell. I only have very basic knowledge on HTML and javascript.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./javascript.js"></script>
    <h1> Test A2 </h1>
  </head>  
    <body onload="disableButton()">
      <p>No. of Cols :
      <input id="noOfCols" type="text" name="cols"/>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
         No. of Rows :
      <input id="noOfRows" type="text" name="rows"/></p>

      <p>Sample Cell Data :
      <input id="scd" type="text" name="scdata"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      Cell Height (in pixels) :
      <input id="height" type="text" name="chip"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      Cell Width (in pixels) :
      <input id="width" type="text" name="cwip"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      Cell Background Colour :
        <select id="bgcolour" class="colour" name="cbc">
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="purple">Purple</option>
        <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
        <option value="pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      </select>
      </p>

      <button id="generate" onClick="generate()">Generate Table</button>
      <button id="delete" onClick="deleteTable()">Clear Table</button><hr/>

      <p id=generatedTable></p>

      <hr/>
    </body>
 </html>


function disableButton()
{
  document.getElementById("delete").disabled = true; 
}

function generate()
{
  document.getElementById("delete").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("generate").disabled = true;

  var myTable = document.getElementById("generatedTable");

  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border ='1';

  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  var rows = document.getElementById("noOfRows");
  var row = Number(rows.value);

  var cols = document.getElementById("noOfCols");
  var col = Number(cols.value); 

  for (var y=0; y<row; y++)
  {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var x=0; x<col; x++)
    {     
      var td = document.createElement('TD');

      var cellwidth = document.getElementById("width");
      var widthcell = cellwidth.value;
      td.width = widthcell;
      var cellheight = document.getElementById("height");
      var heightcell = cellheight.value;
      td.height = heightcell;
      td.align = "center";

      var cellId = "Cell [" + x + ", " + y + "]";
      td.setAttribute("id", cellId.toString());

      td.addEventListener("mouseover", modifyColor, false); 
      td.addEventListener("click", clickWhite, false);

      var celltextInput = document.getElementById("scd");
      var cell = celltextInput.value; 
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cell));
      tr.appendChild(td);  
    }  
  }   

  myTable.appendChild(table);
}

const modifyColor = event => 
{
  const color = document.querySelector(".colour");
  event.target.style.background = color.value;
}

const clickWhite = event =>
{
  const color = document.querySelector(".colour");
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

function deleteTable() 
{
  document.getElementById("generate").disabled = false;
  var removeTable = document.getElementById("generatedTable");
  removeTable.innerHTML = "";
}
```

I expected the table to show the cell row and column numbers after using the setAttribute function but nothing appears.

Comment: Change your line td.setAttribute("id", cellId.toString()); to td.innerHTML=cellId.toString();

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! But however when a value in written into Sample Cell Data textbox, it shows both the value as well as the Cell [" + x + ", " + y + "]. How do I allow the entered value to replace the default value? Or when nothingnis enterend only the Cell [" + x + ", " + y + "] will be show. Thanks!!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problems by

- making each cell be contentEditable on creation, allowing you to edit the cell when you click it
- erasing the previous contents of the cell so you can type whatever you want
- using the sample cell data text box instead of the cell ID if it is filled in
- I disabled the Clear Table button in the HTML instead of running a script on page load that does it

I also removed some of your color options and added line breaks just for aesthetics

```js
function generate() {
  document.getElementById("delete").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("generate").disabled = true;
  var myTable = document.getElementById("generatedTable");
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border ='1';
  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  var rows = document.getElementById("noOfRows");
  var row = Number(rows.value);
  var cols = document.getElementById("noOfCols");
  var col = Number(cols.value);
  for (var y=0; y<row; y++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    for (var x=0; x<col; x++) {     
      var td = document.createElement('TD');
      var cellwidth = document.getElementById("width");
      var widthcell = cellwidth.value;
      td.width = widthcell;
      var cellheight = document.getElementById("height");
      var heightcell = cellheight.value;
      td.height = heightcell;
      td.align = "center";
      td.contentEditable = "true";
      td.addEventListener("mouseover", modifyColor, false); 
      td.addEventListener("click", clickWhite, false);
      var cellId = "Cell [" + x + ", " + y + "]";
      var celltextInput = document.getElementById("scd");
      var cell = celltextInput.value;
      if (document.getElementById("scd").value == "") {
       td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellId.toString()));
      } else {
       td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cell));
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);  
    }  
  }
  myTable.appendChild(table);
}

const modifyColor = event => {
  const color = document.querySelector(".colour");
  event.target.style.background = color.value;
}

const clickWhite = event => {
  const color = document.querySelector(".colour");
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  event.target.innerHTML = "";
}

function deleteTable() {
  document.getElementById("generate").disabled = false;
  var removeTable = document.getElementById("generatedTable");
  removeTable.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<p>No. of Cols :
<input id="noOfCols" type="text" name="cols"/><br />
No. of Rows :
<input id="noOfRows" type="text" name="rows"/></p>
<p>Sample Cell Data :
<input id="scd" type="text" name="scdata"/><br />
Cell Height (in pixels) :
<input id="height" type="text" name="chip"/><br />
Cell Width (in pixels) :
<input id="width" type="text" name="cwip"/><br />
Cell Background Colour :
<select id="bgcolour" class="colour" name="cbc">
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="white">White</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
</p>
<button id="generate" onClick="generate()">Generate Table</button>
<button id="delete" onClick="deleteTable()" disabled="disabled">Clear Table</button>
<hr/>
<p id=generatedTable></p>
<hr/>
```